# Operating on Spark data frames with SparkR and Sparklyr - unrealistic settings?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, sparklyr

I am currently working with the SparkR and sparklyr package and I think that they are not suitable for high-dimensional sparse data sets.

Both packages have the paradigm that you can select/filter columns and rows of data frames by simple logical conditions on a few columns or rows. But this is often not what you would do on such large data sets. There you need to select rows and columns based on the values of hundreds of row or column entries. Often, you first have to calculate statistics on each row/column, and then use these values for the selections. Or, you want to address certain values in the data frame only.

For example,

1. How can I select all rows or columns that have less than 75% missing values?
2. How can I impute missing values with column- or row-specific values that were derived from each column or row?
3. To solve (#2), I need to execute functions on each row or column of a data frame separately. However, even functions like dapplyCollect of SparkR do not really help, as they [are far too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619057/how-to-count-number-of-missing-values-for-each-column-of-a-data-frame-with-spark).

Maybe I am missing something, but I would say that SparkR and sparklyr do not really help in these situations. Am I wrong?

As a side note, I do not understand how libraries like MLlib or H2O [could be integrated with Sparklyr](http://spark.rstudio.com/mllib.html) if there are such severe limitations, e.g. in handling missing values.

Comment: I would use sql for that. Perhaps you can use `Drill` instead of `Spark`?, take a look at the `sergeant` package if you want to use `Drill` via `R`. I share your frustration using Spark via `SparkR` or `sparklyr`. For me it has been a nightmare. It's kind of picky and fail-prone with large datasets. Perhaps it's because I still do not fully understand how to properly configure Spark, but for the moment I process large datasets using a traditional sql server or even using Drill (which I found it much more stable) and then pass only clean data (ready to run models) to Spark, to use `MLlib`.